# glBufferData seperates data with 0

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I tried loading my indices into an `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but when when I try this it separates my data with 0's.

So for instance I loaded this data:

> ```
> [0 1 3 3 1 2]
> ```

with the function `glBufferData` (look at code sample below). When I ask for the data in the buffer with `glGenBufferSubData`, this function returns the following:

> ```
> [0 0 1 0 3 0 3 0 1 0 2 0].
> ```

```py
def __bindIndicesBuffer__(self, indices):
        vboID = glGenBuffers(1)
        self.vbos.append(vboID)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12, numpy.array(indices, dtype = numpy.int16), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        print(glGetBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 12))
```

In the function `glBufferData` I have to reserve 12 bytes of data, which is weird because I only have 6 numbers. Anybody has a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the function `glBufferData` I have to reserve 12 bytes of data, which is weird because I only have 6 numbers [...]

Of course, each of you your numbers is of type `int16`, this means each number has 16 bits respectively 2 bytes (1 byte has 8 bits). 6 numbers with 2 bytes need 12 bytes of memory. Since the size parameter in [`glBufferData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferData.html) is the size in bytes, the parameter has to be 12.

---

> [...] when I try this it separates my data with 0's [...]

[`glGetBufferSubData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGetBufferSubData.html) reads the byte values of the buffer and returns a array of `uint8` values. So each of the 12 bytes is treated as a separate 8 bit (`unit8`) value, that is what is printed.

If you want to get the "orginal" `int16` values, then you've to reinterpret the array by [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html)

```py
uint8_data = glGetBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 12)
int16_data = numpy.frombuffer(uint8_data, dtype=numpy.int16)
print(int16_data)
```

Alternatively you can treat the data pointer to a `int16` array as a `unit8` data pointer (see [`numpy.ndarray.ctypes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html)):

```py
int16_data = numpy.empty([6], dtype=numpy.int16)
unit8_ptr  = int16_data.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 12, unit8_ptr)
print(int16_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving GL 6 numbers, each a 16-bit integer (`numpy.int16`), i.e. each number takes 2 bytes. When printing the bytes are printed individually, so you see 12 separate numbers. You can confirm / experiment with giving GL numbers that are larger than 255, i.e. their most significant byte will not be zero anymore.

Also of interest – the numbers seem to be written in low-endian format, i.e. least significant byte first. So if you write the `int16` 300, you *should* see `[... 44 1 ...]` in the single-byte output, because `44 + 1 * 256 = 300`.